# How to show the volume preserving mean curvature flow preserve volume?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

As picture below, I want to show the volume enclosed by $M_t$ is constant. Because 
$$
V(t)=\frac{1}{n}\int_{M_t} F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t) dS
$$
And $\partial_t\sqrt g=-H(H-h)\sqrt g$, so
$$
\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{n}\int_{M_t} [\partial_tF(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t) +F(x,t)\cdot \partial_t\nu(x,t)-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t)] dS    \\
=\frac{1}{n}\int_{M_t} [(h(t)-H(x,t))\nu(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t) +F(x,t)\cdot \partial_t\nu(x,t)-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t)] dS    \\
=\frac{1}{n}\int_{M_t}[F(x,t)\cdot \partial_t\nu(x,t)-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t)] dS
$$
Then,  to show $\int_{M_t}[F(x,t)\cdot \partial_t\nu(x,t)-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t)] dS  =0$

Because $\nu(x,t)$ is outer unit normal vector. We have $\langle\nu(x,t),\nu(x,t)\rangle=1$. Then
$$
\langle  \partial_t\nu(x,t),\nu(x,t)   \rangle=0   
$$
Besides, $\{ \partial_iF \}$ is a basis of $T_xM$, so we can assume 
$$
\partial_t\nu (x,t)=v^i\partial_iF
$$
Then, we have 
$$
\partial_t\nu= \langle \partial_t\nu, \partial_jF\rangle \partial_j F g^{ij}
$$
Because $\langle \nu, \partial_jF\rangle = 0$, we have $\langle \partial_t\nu, \partial_jF\rangle =-\langle \nu, \partial_t\partial_jF\rangle$. Then
$$
\partial_t\nu=\langle \nu,\partial_i(H\nu) \rangle \partial_jF g^{ij}=\partial_iH \partial_jFg^{ij}=\nabla H  ~~~~~\text{gradient on M}
$$
So
$$
F(x,t)\cdot \partial_t\nu(x,t)-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t)   \\
=F\cdot\nabla H-H(H-h)F(x,t)\cdot \nu(x,t) 
$$ 
Then, I get stuck.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [image]

Comment: You're pretty much there. If the volume is constant in time then $V(0)=V(t)$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Differentiating this (since $V(0)$ is independent of $t$) gives $\frac{dV(t)}{dt} =0$.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused  how to show  $\frac{dV(t)}{dt} =0$ ?

Comment: It is a simple deduction from the first variation formula and divergence theorem, then the direct definition of $h(t)$.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused  Could you detail explain it ? In my calculation, there always  be $\nabla H$, $H$ is mean curvature,  I don't know how to deal $\nabla H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple,  so I'm not going to try to read your long calculation. If you move a surface in the outwards normal direction at speed $f(x)$, then the enclosed volume changes by $dV/dt = \int f dA$. Since $h$ is defined as the average of $H$, $h-H$ has average $0$, and thus $dV/dt = \int (h - H) dA = 0$.

Comment: Thanks , let me find where is my mistake.

Comment: Could you show $dV/dt = \int f dA$ ?  I fail to show it.

Comment: I know where is my mistake.  Total space is Euclid space. So, for general Riemannian manifold's submanifold, this is not true. I confuse them. Sorry for my tiresome.

Comment: Do you have a reference/a proof for the fact you state here?

Comment: @F.T. I don't know a great reference, but here's one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_evolution_of_integrals#Volume_integrals